# How to test ngIf, whose right operand is relevant to a FormControl?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I used ngIf to show some message like this in *.html:

```
<input name="name" id="name" formControlName="name" required>
<span *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" id="message">
   Some messages
</span>
```

and now I want to check whether it takes effect. So, in *spec.ts, I set the right operand of that ngIf to true(success verified by "expect") and then use the debugElement to query it by id. Unfortunately, the returned value of the query is null. I think it means the span above has not been created yet.

I've tried to use "detectChanges" after I set the value of "name" and mark it as dirty, it still doesn't work. Another way I've tried is to assign the value of that HTMLInputElement directly and then use "dispatchEvent", still doesn't work.

I utilized jasmine and karma to test my Angular 4 application.  Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What's this `<span<input`?

Comment: sorry, it's a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to test it. Some steps may not be required, but I threw everything at it.

```
  it('should not show error messages when input is valid', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const messages = compiled.querySelector('#message');
    expect(messages).toBeFalsy();
  }));

  it('should show error messages when input is invalid', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const input = component.formGroup.controls['name'];
    input.setValue('')
    input.markAsTouched();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => { 
      const messages = compiled.querySelector('#message');
      expect(messages).toBeTruthy();
    });
  }));
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)  I forgot to initialize the component. Now it works!

Answer (score 2):

ngif is not correct, you have to change it

```
*ngIf not ngIf

<span *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" id="message">
    Some messages
</span>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. I've changed it.